# Calibre's CHM conversion from PDF

Tags: pdf, ebook, file-conversion, chm, calibre

I am trying to convert PDF to CHM. 
However, I see only these fileformats in the output dialog:

[image]

Nothing of these is CHM.
However, some may be similar.

### HTMLZ

I did a conversion to HTMLZ which seems to work in section -sense. 
However, Calibri's E-book viewer is buggish and in overflow.

I run `file Kaplan.htmlz` and I see `Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract` which is different than CHM i.e. `MS Windows HtmlHelp Data`. 
I do not think Zip archive data is a good choice for a fast search in section sense and in titles.

`brew search htmlz` gives nothing so not so popular format in OSX.

**How can you convert PDF to CHM?**
I am open to any other formats which are as fast as CHM.

Comment: "I am open to any other formats which are as fast as CHM." - Why, is PDF not fast enough for you?

Comment: @Karan PDF is very slow. It does the search from start to the end. PDF is not an option.

Comment: "It does the search from start to the end." - That sounds like such a weird thing to say. My PDF reader searches forward from the current page and only wraps around when it reaches the end. So if your PDF reader always searches from page 1, blame it. The format itself is not slow.

Comment: It is! It processes all data. Beginning or your current location onwards.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not possible using ***calibre***.

As you can see from the calibre documentation quoted below, CHM is only an import format and not an output format.

Also there are problems with importing PDF documents in calibre.

- [What formats does calibre support conversion to/from?](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/faq.html#what-formats-does-calibre-support-conversion-to-from)

> ***calibre*** supports the conversion of many input formats to many output formats. It can convert every input format in the following list, to every output format.

> **Input Formats:** AZW, AZW3, AZW4, CBZ, CBR, CB7, CBC, CHM, DJVU, DOCX, EPUB, FB2, FBZ, HTML, HTMLZ, LIT, LRF, MOBI, ODT, PDF, PRC, PDB, PML, RB, RTF, SNB, TCR, TXT, TXTZ

> **Output Formats:** AZW3, EPUB, DOCX, FB2, HTMLZ, OEB, LIT, LRF, MOBI, PDB, PMLZ, RB, PDF, RTF, SNB, TCR, TXT, TXTZ, ZIP

- [Convert PDF documents](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/conversion.html#pdfconversion)

> PDF documents are one of the worst formats to convert from. They are a fixed page size and text placement format. Meaning, it is very difficult to determine where one paragraph ends and another begins. calibre will try to unwrap paragraphs using a configurable, Line un-wrapping factor. This is a scale used to determine the length at which a line should be unwrapped. Valid values are a decimal between 0 and 1. The default is 0.45, just under the median line length. Lower this value to include more text in the unwrapping. Increase to include less. You can adjust this value in the conversion settings under PDF Input.